# Consulta sql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Possuo uma tabela com datas e gostaria que criar uma consulta que me retorne registros com datas anteriores ao dia atual mas não consegui montar essa consulta; segue abaixo meu código e imagem do BD:

```
function get_late_events($sort = 'idevento', $order = 'asc', $limit =null, $offset = null) {
    $this->db->order_by($sort, $order);

    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    }

    $this->db->select('idevento, cnome, inicio, fim, descricaoEvento, user, importancia');
    $this->db->from('eventos');
    $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.ccod = eventos.nomeEvento');
    $this->db->where('inicio', '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Banco de dados: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A consulta **SQL** normal em **PHP** ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
$data = date('Y-m-d'); 

$sqlq = "

SELECT idevento, cnome, inicio, fim, descricaoEvento, user, importancia
FROM eventos xxx
LEFT JOIN clientes zzz ON (zzz.ccod = xxx.nomeEvento)
WHERE xxx.inicio = '$data'
ORDER BY xxx.inicio ASC

"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acabei resolvendo da seguinte forma e funcionou

```
$this->db->where('inicio <', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Marque sua resposta ;)